# Draw Control To Bitmap That Is Not On Screen

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have an application that is quite graphics heavy I have lots of different panels with transparent controls, stretched background images and a large number of controls.

If I hide 1 panel and show the next the rendering is awful it can flicker and generally take a good couple of seconds to be ready.

Now I've toyed around with double buffering, freeze painting and CreateParams and it looks like I'm just beyond what Winforms was ever designed to do graphically.

So is it possible to load all of my controls onto a panel and perform a DrawToBitmap of sorts while the controls are invisible or off screen? Then just display the bitmap on screen?

I have tried drawing them visible and at -2000, -2000 bit it doesn't give me an image.
I have tried drawing them with visible set to false and them on screen and I don't get an image back.

Comment: Can you post some code where the flicker occurs?

Comment: Impossible to answer until you show what you are doing.

Comment: I can't really post any code, I'm talking about several thousand lines of code. I have a main form which loads say 5 different panels (but this can vary). Each panel then goes and queries a database in a background worker and upon completion builds and adds a number of user controls. Also I'm not sure this is of any relevance, I'm not asking how to stop flickering I'm asking if you can perform a drawtobitmap like action without displaying the panel the controls are on on the screen.